# Windows 10 laptop battery drains during sleep

Tags: windows-10, battery, asus-laptop

I have a Windows 10 laptop (Asus UX305L) that will drain its entire battery even when in sleep mode. I've checked my power settings and they seem normal. I don't have any wake timers set and when I run powercfg -lastwake to see what process ran, it doesn't return anything.

I ran a battery report and I can see my laptop woke at 9:51:12 AM and stayed active ~7 hours before hibernating because the battery was at 5%. Is there anyway I can see what exactly ran at this time?

[image: Battery Report Screenshot]

The only program open was Chrome and I had zero usb peripherals plugged in so I don't think it was any drivers or programs preventing sleep. Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try closing Chrome to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: use **powercfg /srumutil** to get a detailed per app usage report: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-157-Energy-Estimation-Engine-E3

Comment: ave you watched the video and tried the powercfg command to analyze battery usage?

Comment: If you want no battery drain and saved state, why not hibernate?  Sleep explicitly keeps power flowing to a number of components.